# Android. Strange crash in charAt (setSelection)

Tags: android, selection, indexoutofboundsexception, charat

I have a very strange crash in application. 
Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: -1 < 0
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.charAt(SpannableStringBuilder.java:112)
at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:84)
at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:127)
at android.widget.Editor$InsertionHandleView.updateSelection(Editor.java:4971)
at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.positionAtCursorOffset(Editor.java:4647)
at android.widget.Editor$HandleView.updatePosition(Editor.java:4675)
at android.widget.Editor$PositionListener.onPreDraw(Editor.java:2714)
at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:711)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2097)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1179)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4859)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler.handleMessage(Choreographer.java:664)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I got the stack trace without any links on my application's packages (classes/methods). 
Has anyone encountered this problem? Thx.

**EDIT**

Can you see, the stack trace has not any links on my application's packages/classes, but app anyway crashed.

**UPD**
I use Selection.setSelection. I don't use SpannableStringBuilder.

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if (!s.toString().isEmpty()) {
        Selection.setSelection(s, s.length());
    }   
}
```

Comment: What are you passing in for charAt(index)?

Comment: Kindly, show us some code

Comment: IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: could u change the s.length to s.length-1 and check ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be an OS bug which require a combination of a certain OS version(e.g. 4.1.2) and a certain device(e.g. Galaxy S3 I9300). This is not your problem. Unfortunately I don't know how to get around this either.

I'm curious how you ran into this issue. Based on the callstack, my guess is you tap on a textview and tried to paste text from clipboard.

Comment: I'm running into a similar problem. The post is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27447117/indexoutofboundsexception-on-samsung-devices

Comment: i'm also facing the same issue in samsung devices..is there any workaround?

Answer (score -1):

Read the first line... it says `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: -1 < 0`. The problem is your string does not have the character you  are searching for. Post the code. Then we will see what's wrong...

Comment: Can you see, the stack trace has not any links on my application's packages/classes, but app anyway crashed.

Comment: Well, where do you use a `SpannableStringBuilder`?

Comment: @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (!s.toString().isEmpty()) {
            Selection.setSelection(s, s.length());
        }