# IndexOutOfBoundsException on Samsung devices

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception, samsung-mobile

I'm getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException on Samsung Galaxy S5 and Note 3 and 4. It doesn't reference my code. Has anyone encountered this? I haven't been able to find anything on here.

It appears to be occasionally happening when try to long-click on the EditText to paste something in.

Edit:

I'm using a simple EditText field (not in ListView or Spinner). There's a hint of around 28 characters. I'm toggling the focus via `clearFocus` a few times and I'm using a `setOnEditorActionListener` and `setOnFocusChangeListener` that control attaching a fragment to the Activity.

Edit #2:

I've been able to successfully reproduce it by trying to long press on the EditText to try to paste something. It only happens when there is text already in the EditText and I long press to the RIGHT of the text, not on it. Also, the EditText must not have focus.

Any possible solution by creating a custom EditText and overriding some methods?

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (11 ... 11) ends beyond length 0
   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1024)
   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:594)
   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:590)
   at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:116)
   at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:127)
   at android.widget.Editor.performLongClick(Editor.java:1008)
   at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:10637)
   at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:19482)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5678)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            String searchText = v.getText().toString();

            FragmentSearchList fragmentSearchList = (FragmentSearchList) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_SEARCH_LIST_TAG);

            if(fragmentSearchList != null){
                fragmentSearchList.executeSearch(searchText);
            }

            return true;
        }

    });

editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus){

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();

                Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_SEARCH_LIST_TAG);

                if(fragment == null){

                    editText.setText(null);

                    FragmentSearchList fragmentSearchList = FragmentSearchList.newInstance();

                    FragmentTransaction fragmentSearchListTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentSearchListTransaction.add(R.id.viewGroupFragmentSearchListContainer, fragmentSearchList, FRAGMENT_SEARCH_LIST_TAG);
                    fragmentSearchListTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragmentSearchListTransaction.commit();

                }
            }
            else{

                if(!isRemovingOrPartOfRemovalChain()){
                    editText.setText(mAreaName);
                    getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                }

            }
        }

    });


public boolean isRemovingOrPartOfRemovalChain(){

    if(isRemoving()){
        return true;
    }

    Fragment fragment = this.getParentFragment();

    if(fragment != null){
        if(((MainFragment)fragment).isRemovingOrPartOfRemovalChain()){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    else{
        return(this.getActivity().isFinishing());
    }

}
```

Comment: are you using listview or spinner?;you must post your code

Comment: No it's just a plain EditText. Check my edit

Comment: WHAT IS THE CODE IN "setOnEditorActionListener"and onlongclicklistner

Comment: Please post more code in order for people to debug.

Comment: @ono Could be a timing issue. On gaining focus, you call `editText.setText(null);`. Try commenting out this statement, or delaying it using a Handler.

Comment: you may try this  'editText.setText("");' alternate for  'editText.setText(null);'

Comment: @Elango `editText.setText("")` won't make a difference since the `null` argument is replaced by `""` itself. Take a look at the overridden `TextView#setText(CharSequence, BufferType, boolean, int)`.

Comment: So commenting out the `editText.setText(null)` removes the crash, although it doesn't clear the current text. What's also interesting on other devices where it doesn't crash, the logcat gives me `E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length`. So it looks like it is an Android problem and not just Samsung.

Comment: @ono The "SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length" sometimes occur depending on the keyboard you're using (SwiftKey in particular is a big offender in this regard) even when doing nothing in particular. It might be related, but not necessarily.

Comment: @one It's likely that using `Handler.post()` as @Vikram suggested will enable you to clear the `EditText` and avoid the exception.

Comment: Do you have more than one thread? If so, you could consider a `synchronize` around `OnEditorActionListener` and `OnFocusChangeListener`

Comment: @matiash @ono There might be another way. To avoid the exception, you need to stop the long-press action from kicking in. So, before calling `editText.setText(null)`, call `editText.cancelLongPress()`. The side effect of this will be that you won't see the `PASTE` action popup. To see the `PASTE` action, user will have to lift their finger and try long-pressing again.

Comment: I'm ok with just removing the `editText.setText(null)`. I think the UX is acceptable.